# JVM memory limit on Linux (Debian)

Tags: linux, java, limit

When running my java program, I get following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
```

I am wondering how I can increase the limits on my system, so that my program does not crash. Also, how can I print the current limits?

Comment: Check [this answer on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3571231/586014). Also instead of increasing memory you might want to check why your application uses so much (unless it is supposed to be memory heavy because of the used algorithm).